# How to Open pdf files with different paths in Java

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I have a PDF file and I want to open it with my java Application. PDF file open when I run the that program with Netbeans. But when I run that program from .Jar file , That PDF file didn't open.

```
    try {
            String p1[] = getClass().getResource("/Scholars_Management_System_Help.pdf").toString().split("file:/");
            String helppath = p1[1].replace("%20", " ");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + helppath);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: Could you please *format* this a bit. And, **add the error message, stacktrace** or what else you have as indication of an error.

Comment: it doesn't come any error massage

Comment: So where do you know it didn't open?

Comment: when I click on the button, It does not open

Comment: Did you ever try to run the command you are constructing from the command line? If not, you should. Show the complete command before executing it for debugging, then go to a cmd window and try the same command. Maybe you get helpful error messages then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `getClass().getResource("/Scholars_Management_System_Help.pdf")` locates a file called Scholars_Management_System_Help.pdf in your project root directory and when you create the jar file this file is probably not included in the jar, and that's why this is not working. You should probably run the jar from a command line inorder for you to see if there is any exception thrown. That way you could be sure of the cause of the problem.

Again instead of running the application (pdf reader) with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + helppath);` you should instead use `Desktop.getDesktop().open(file_name);` which makes it more portable.

Answer (score 1):

Friend

Try to use this method for opening pdf files in netbeans

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.File;

 public class pdfdemo{
    public ststic void main(String args[]) throws Exception
      {
       try{

           String fil = "d:\\text.pdf";
           Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(fil));
          }
       catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
           }
      } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make the rundll32 program open a file that doesn't exist, since the PDF file is *inside* your jar, and not on the file system. Store it outside of your jar if you want it to be accessible from external programs.

And instead of just displaying "Error" when you have an IOException, why don't you print the message and stack trace of the exception: it would explain why and where you get the error:

```
ex.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: when I run it with Netbeans thet PDF file will open

Comment: Yes, because when you run it from NetBeans, the file is on the file system, and not inside a jar.